# Show that a subsequence of recursively defined sequence is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

*Consider a sequence $(x_n)$ that is defined recursively:*
*$$
\begin{cases}
x_0 = 1 \\
x_{n+1} = 1/(x_n + 1), n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{cases}
$$*

*Prove, that subsequence $(x_{2n})_n$ is decreasing, and subsequence $(x_{2n+1})_n$ is increasing.*

I know how to handle subsequences when a sequence is defined explicitly using $n$ but I don't know how to do it in this case. What are some steps I could start with to prove that? Is there a general approach to handle subsequences when we have only a recursive formula?

I tried to write down the first terms:
$(x_{2n})_n = (1, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{5}{8}, ...)$,
$(x_{2n+1})_n = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{5}, \frac{8}{13}, ...)$ but it didn't really helped.

Comment: The general approach is to use induction. Your goal is to prove that $x_{2n} \ge x_{2(n+1)}$ for all $n$; use induction.

Comment: And to prove $x_{2n+1} \le x_{2(n+1)+1}$, also use induction.

Comment: A good start is to write $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $x_{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}, and$$
$$v_n=x_{2n}$$
then
$$v_{n+1}=(f \circ f)(v_n)$$

with
$$(f\circ f)(x)=\frac{x+1}{x+2}$$

Use the fact that $ f\circ f$ is increasing  at $ [0,+\infty)$ and that
$$v_1=\frac 23 <v_0$$